# Can you compile JS to native executable?

Tags: javascript, compilation

Is it possible to compile JS to a native executable? I have seen NodeJS run JS, but can you actually compile javascript, either by a wrapper or actual compiler.

Comment: Native to what? What architecture are you referring to?

Comment: Of course it's *possible*. I'm not aware of any compiler that does it, though.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is of course theoretically possible, but when the Javascript source uses 'eval', the compiled executable would (at least in some cases) have to include a Javascript engine or compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean compile to native code. Not directly.  NodeJs uses the V8 engine which compiles javascript to native code during execution.

You can freely download and compile the V8 engine.

https://developers.google.com/v8/

Comment: The question opens with *"Is it possible to compile JS to a native executable?"* The answer is, of course, **yes**. It's just a language, after all. I'm not aware of any compiler that actually does it, though. Important distinction, that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Your point is valid.  That's why I added the "Not directly".

Answer (score 0):

> Javascript is (as name) script lang.
>   So if you want convert a web application to desk application there are many solutions like chrome applications, mozilla applications, pokki, whatever...
>   so google, read and make.

[mozilla developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Developing/installable_apps)

[pokki applications developers](https://developers.pokki.com/)

[chrome developers](https://developers.google.com/chrome/)